# maven - why is dependency check skipped?

Tags: maven

In my pom plugins I have...

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.owasp</groupId>
            <artifactId>dependency-check-maven</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>check</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

But when I run `mvn dependency-check:check` or `mvn verify` in the logs I see

```
[INFO] --- dependency-check-maven:6.2.2:check (default-cli) @ my-project ---
[INFO] Skipping dependency-check
```

How do I get it to run??

Comment: Weird this should work...   Tested on my side and it works as expected.
Do you have any  `<properties>` or `<configuration>` which could skip it ? (see https://jeremylong.github.io/DependencyCheck/dependency-check-maven/check-mojo.html#skip)

Comment: Try with `mvn -X ...` maybe in debug logs you find a reason

Comment: Cheers sbernard. There was a property that referenced another property that set skip to true.

Comment: Dear @RobHay, Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you have solved the problem. Please, consider posting an answer and [accepting the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned out the `dependency-check.skip` was evaluating to true in the properties.

I simply set it to `false`.